# How to exclude a package from a Class Library NuGet package?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a `.NET Standard` class library project that will be built into a NuGet package. I've installed the `docfx.console` package so that I can generate a documentation website every time I build.

Now when another project installs my library's NuGet package, the `docfx.console` NuGet package also gets installed - which I don't want.

In the project properties under Package, I have selected **Generate NuGet package on build**. This would automatically generate the NuGet package for my library when I build it. But in this tab, I don't see anywhere where I can configure to exclude any packages.

So in order to exclude the `docfx.console` package, I created a .nuspec file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <!-- Required elements-->
    <id>My.Library</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <description>My Library's project dscription.</description>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <copyright>My Copyright (c)</copyright>

    <!-- Optional elements -->
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="docfx.console" version="2.36.1" exclude="build" />
    </dependencies>
    <!-- ... -->
  </metadata>
  <!-- Optional 'files' node -->
</package>
```

But it isn't working. How can I correct it to exclude the `docfx.console` package when building the NuGet package?

Or, is there any other way I could exclude the `docfx.console` package from the NuGet package?

Comment: Try add `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` to `PackageReference` of `docfx.console` in your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to exclude a package from a Class Library NuGet package?

According to the NuGet official documentation [Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets):

> You might be using a dependency purely as a development harness and
>   might not want to expose that to projects that will consume your
>   package. In this scenario, you can use the PrivateAssets metadata to
>   control this behavior.
>
> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>     <!-- ... -->
>
>     <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.0">
>         <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
>     </PackageReference>
>
>     <!-- ... -->
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

So, just as UserName commented, you can add `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` to `PackageReference` of `docfx.console` in your project.

**To accomplish this**, edit your project file `.csproj` like following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="docfx.console" Version="2.36.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Or

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="docfx.console" Version="2.36.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

If you are using `.nuspec` file, you should move the following dependency info in your `.nuspec` file:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="docfx.console" version="2.36.1" />
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Although this successfully hides the dependency,  in my case I have a situation where I hide the dependencies in the child project, I then obtain  the child via nuget in the parent and call some methods on the child which use the dependency.  In this case I get a TypeInitilazationEcxception,  with  System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'NLog ...  In my case I was wrapping Nlog in our Tools lib and calling the wrapper.  any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @shelbypereira The fix is to not hide dependencies that the consumer of your package needs.

Comment: @JonathanAllen agree dependencies should not be hidden if the consumer needs it. Sounds like that's not the case here - the user-facing library itself has a dependency on NLog, which is not exposed to the user.  So it makes sense to me that NLog be included in the nupkg, but not exposed to the consumer.  However, using PrivateAssets=all here will remove it from the package; not using will have it in the package, but make it available to the consumer.  Is there any middle-way here?

Comment: @shelbypereira I think I might have found what you are looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72723880/1399272 - try using PrivateAssets compile instead of all.  That will make it where you can't compile against the internal assembly, but it's not making runtime private so you still get to use the internal assembly in runtime.